# nw.js не работает с php файлами

Tags: php, html, nw.js

Сделал сайт на php, решил сделать десктопный клиент, используя nw.js, но столкнулся с проблемой: при запуске nw.js он выдаёт не страницу, а php код. Если этот фреймворк не работает с php, то подскажите пожалуйста другой.